# Could not connect a Python client to Azure Cosmo Bd : Import pydocumentdb fails

Tags: python, azure

I work on a Mac with Python 2.7 built in install

I installed pip with `sudo easy_install pip`

I installed azure with `sudo pip install azure`

Now I wrote a simple python client for azure :

```
import pydocumentdb
from pydocumentdb import errors
from pydocumentdb import documents
from pydocumentdb import document_client

import config as cfg

HOST = cfg.settings['host']
MASTER_KEY = cfg.settings['master_key']
DATABASE_ID = cfg.settings['database_id']
COLLECTION_ID = cfg.settings['collection_id']

database_link = 'dbs/' + DATABASE_ID

@staticmethod
def list_collections(client):
        print("\n5. List all Collection in a Database")

        print('Collections:')

        collections = list(client.ReadCollections(database_link))

        if not collections:
            return

        for collection in collections:
            print(collection['id'])

def run_sample():

    with IDisposable(document_client.DocumentClient(HOST, {'masterKey': MASTER_KEY} )) as client:
        try:
            # list all collection on an account
            list_collections(client)  
        except errors.HTTPFailure as e:
            print('\nrun_sample has caught an error. {0}'.format(e.message))

        finally:
            print("\nrun_sample done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run_sample()

    except Exception as e:
            print("Top level Error: args:{0}, message:{1}".format(e.args,e.message))
```

Then when I run the program I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ReadDatabase.py", line 1,
>   in 
>       import pydocumentdb ImportError: No module named pydocumentdb

So I read two causes :
Azure not installed or problem with Sys.path

I did a sample to show sys.path

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.path
```

Giving me the result :

```
['/Users/xxx/coding/python/projects/document_client', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/adal-0.5.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-11.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/msrest-0.4.26-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.1.4-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyJWT-1.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/certifi-2018.1.18-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/isodate-0.6.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib-0.8.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipaddress-1.0.19-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cffi-1.11.4-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/idna-2.6-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauthlib-2.0.6-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycparser-2.18-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

So I do not see Azure libs.

Answer (score 1):

In fact i thought pydocumentdb was part of Azure Python SDK and it's not the case
Doing `pip install pydocumentdb` solved the problem